# How to start the Cinnamon desktop environment from CentOS terminal?

Tags: terminal, centos, cinnamon

I installed CentOS 7.2 using the minimal ISO. How to start the Cinnamon desktop environment from CentOS terminal? I installed, ran `yum update` and the following instructions all successfully though I have no idea how to start Cinnamon.

```
yum install epel-release
yum groupinstall "X Window System"
yum install cinnamon gdm liberation* gnome-terminal gnome-icon-theme-legacy.noarch
echo "exec /usr/bin/cinnamon-session" >> ~/.xinitrc
ln -s /etc/systemd/system/default.target /lib/systemd/system/runlevel5.target
yum update
reboot
```

Comment: Try `startx` ...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch AWESOME! Please post as an answer so I can accept! I couldn't find this any where after thorough searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should use [startx(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/startx) (for [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) based desktops). Read also about [xinit(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xinit)

Notice that some distributions are switching to [Wayland](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/) so the details would be different.